# Larvavel relationships issue or I got mixed up

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a table called proposals which has the following

id, job_id, user_id, created

I also have a jobs table which has the following:

id, user_id, title, description

So i created a new model called proposals

Which has the following in:

```
 class Proposals extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'proposals';
 public $timestamps = false;

 public function user()
 {
      return $this->belongsTo('User'); // This works fine by calling $proposals->user->email
 }

 public function jobs()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('Jobs'); // This is not working, when i call $proposals->job->title
 }


}
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
 public function workstream()
 {
     $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $proposals = Proposals::where('user_id','=', $user_id)->paginate(5);
     return View::make('jobs/workstream', compact('proposals'))->with('meta_title', 'Workstream');
 }
```

Lastly in my view I have:

```
    @foreach($proposals as $item)
           <p>{{ $item->user->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ ucfirst(substr($item->user->last_name, 0, 1))  }} 
                sent a propopsal for ~  {{ $item->jobs->title }} <a href="">See proposal</a>
           </p>

      @endforeach
```

This {{ $item->jobs->title }} is showing Trying to get property of non-object, so maybe I got myself mixed up here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the `jobs` in the `Proposals` class to `job`

```
public function job()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Jobs');
}
```

After that you can acces `$item->job->title` in your view.

```
@foreach($proposals as $item)
       <p>{{ $item->user->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ ucfirst(substr($item->user->last_name, 0, 1))  }} 
            sent a propopsal for ~  {{ $item->job->title }} <a href="">See proposal</a>
       </p>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Legend cheers, I knew it was something i was doing slightly wrong! Thanks buddy